# how to only insert the filled text inputs?

Tags: php, mysql

this is my code:
`<input type="text" name="text[]" />

<input type="text" name="text[]" />

<input type="text" name="text[]" />`

```
if (!empty($_POST['text'])) {
foreach ($_POST['text'] AS $value) {
    // add to the database
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tableName SET fieldName = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . '"';
}
```

}

I want this to only insert the fields that are filled, for example if the first two inputs are filled, insert those and skip the last one which is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already using `empty()` to check `$_POST` you can also use it to check `$value`

```
if (!empty($_POST['text'])) {
foreach ($_POST['text'] AS $value) {
    // add to the database
    if (!empty($value))
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO tableName SET fieldName = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . '"';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most brain-dead way to solve the problem would be to check the string length of each element in the text array.

```
foreach( $_POST['text'] as $value ) {
    if( !empty( $value ){
        // add to the database
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO tableName SET fieldName = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . '"';
    }
}
```

However, I would seriously consider switching to a framework that does some sort of form validation. I hear good things about [cakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) and [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/), and they may be worth checking out.